# Google App maker Drive files collaboration

Tags: google-app-maker

Does app maker have the options to collaborate drive files to all users in the application.

Currently drive picker uploads files in current user drive, so when several users uploads files it will be uploaded in their drives. So it will not be accessible to all the users in the application.

Does drive picker has the option to configure centralize drive or team drive, so that users can collaborate their files across the application.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible with the Drive Picker. Please note that as per the Drive Picker documentation, the picker does not yet support selecting items in Team Drives. You can confirm this in the official documentation available here https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/picker

I think that Team Drive will be the appropriate solution for your scenario but since this is not available in the Drive Picker yet, you may need to wait until it is officially supported.

Comment: Thank you wilmar, can you suggest any alternatives

Comment: But I need to upload files in Team drive instead of the current user's drive

Comment: You could use DriveApp to remove the file from users Drive and then add file to a specific folder ID which can be an ID to a folder in a Team Drive.